# run php file on interval

Tags: php, file, loops, intervals

I have a dashboard, which plays a video on a set interval.
It also gets some data from google analytics and google analytics realtime, to show this on a google map.
For this, it uses the google maps javascript api and the google analytics reporting php api.
The video is in a separate js file.
The maps (and realtime data) is in a separate php file.
The analytics data is also in a separate php file.

Now, the problem I have is that currently I simply use <`?php include)('filename.php'); ?>` to include them in the `index.php`.
Which works, it outputs the data and map and video I want.

But now I would like to update this information every 15 seconds.
I have tried some `while{ do something; sleep()}` but this gives errors, since it then redeclares previous functions such as `analytics()`.

I have also tried some JavaScript `setInterval()` and include the files that way, but that also doesn't work. Since all the functionality is in those files, how would I go about accomplishing it to update them every 15 seconds?

I have also tried some GET requests, but I don't just want the information, since all the functionality (such as maps and charts) are in those files, so simple data returns don't work either.

So what I want is: re-load (just like when you refresh the page) the `.php` files every 15 seconds.
I don't want to actually refresh the page, since this resets the JavaScript video script as well, which I do not want.

I have read some things about `cronjob`, is it possible to run the .php files on a set interval that way, and will the `index.php` (which includes the other .php files) update automatically as well that way?

Comment: You're looking for a technique called AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML). With AJAX you can send and retrieve data from a server asynchronously (in the background) without interfering with the display and behavior of the existing page.

Comment: Too much work to get into now, since this needs to be done quick, but I will definitely read up on this and when I feel comfortable update it to use AJAX instead. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet here is to wrap the PHP in an iframe, then reload that iframe every 15 seconds like so:

```
const reloadFrame = () =>
   document.getElementById('some_frame_id').contentWindow.location.reload();

setInterval(reloadFrame, 15000);
```

The issue you have is that PHP rendering is all handled server side, so simply throwing a GET request at the server will return the entire rendered page. Unless of course I'm misunderstanding the question and your `filename.php` file will return only the data to update the map, in which case simply write the function to update the map and call it using `setTimeout` recursively.

Comment: Indeed a very simple solution, but it works, which is all I care about. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15">
```

Simply add this in html header

for cronjob

```
# crontab -e
00 15 * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/john/myscript.php
```